# Lets Encrypt Nginx - Your connection is not secure - for wrong subdomains

Tags: nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt, wildcard-subdomain

I have encryption from lets encrypt which is working fine.
My configuration of Nginx allows only SSL connections.
www.example.com, example.com, blog.example.com - all are working fine.

**The problems**

is if a type **www1.example.com** or **blog12.example.com**- there is an error : **Your connection is not secure**

I've read that is related to wildcard certificates - but let's encrypt doesn't support yet.

**Question**

is it possible to change configuration to get server not found error instead of **Your connection is not secure** for those "mistyped" sub-domains?

**Info**

- lets encrypt call

  `sudo letsencrypt certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html -d example.com -d www.example.com`
- `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example`

  ````
  server {
      listen 80 default_server;
      listen [::]:80 default_server;
      server_name example.com www.example.com;
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }

  server {

      # SSL configuration

      listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
      listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
      include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
      include snippets/ssl-params.conf;```

      . . .
  ````

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: So the only way I guess is to allow normal connection (wihtout SSL). Is it harmful to leave it as it is now?

Comment: Please see the answer from @duskwuff. That explains why you propably have that issue. This issue can't be solved on the server thou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a DNS problem.

Your problem is that DNS lookups for `blog12.example.com` (for example) are returning the IP of your web server, instead of returning a NXDOMAIN response. This is probably because you have a wildcard DNS record set up.

To rectify this situation, go to your DNS provider and:

1. Create an A record for each subdomain that you want to have working (e.g, `www.example.com`, `blog.example.com`, *etc*), with the same IP as the current wildcard record.
2. Delete the wildcard record.

Comment: So I've finished was with 2 A records - example.com; blog.example.com; 2 C recrods www.example.com ; *.example.com ; Now I have 3 A records - example.com; blog.example.com; www.example.com and no C records. It's still not updated the DNS. Most probably tonight I'll give a feedback. Thanx again.

Comment: Cool. It's working perfect.